# I need to count the number of equal values in two Hashmap<Integer, String>

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to count the number of same values into two HashMap. Using my code I get only this kind of lines: 161 161: 7252

```
    private static void setGraphEdges(PrintWriter wr, String idP1, String idP2, HashMap<Integer, String> vot1, HashMap<Integer, String> vot2){
    int equalsCounter = 0;
    Set<Integer> listaIdVotazioni = vot1.keySet();
    listaIdVotazioni.retainAll(vot2.keySet());
    String votoparl1;
    String votoparl2;
    for(Integer id : listaIdVotazioni){
        votoparl1 = vot1.get(id);
        votoparl2 = vot2.get(id);
        if(votoparl1.equals(votoparl2)){
            equalsCounter++;
        }
    }
    wr.write(idP2+" "+idP2+": "+equalsCounter+System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

EDIT: using:

```
        Set<Integer> listaIdVotazioni = vot1.keySet();
        listaIdVotazioni.retainAll(vot2.keySet());
```

don't I get the intersection between the two sets of keys?

Comment: I think you want `wr.write(idP1+" "+idP2+...`

Comment: Please add some sample input, expected outputs and what the actual output is so that we can see the issue. Also note that `vot1.keySet()` returns a set backed by the amp, meaning that calling `retainAll()` on it *will modify the actual map*!

Comment: We can't tell where the bug is with such input. Obviously there is a subtle typo in your print statement; but is that really what you are concerned about; or is that number 7252 wrong too? (from looking at your code, it looks OK; except for the thing that I would have that method **return** the equal count; and not to log stuff --- as your method name is absolutely misleading there. I dont see graph edge setting, I just see some counting and logging?!

Comment: Omg, I didn't see the stupid typo. The name of the method It's ok to me because the counters will represent the weights of the edges of a graph.

Comment: I still think your method is **not** following the "single responsibility** principle. The fact that you are providing **three** arguments to it that only deal with **printing** information to some writer is making that very clear.

Comment: You are right, I changed the method keeping HashMap as parameters and returning the counter.. I was hearing the voice of my programming methods proff saying "You are violatin the single responsability principle"

Answer (score 0):

Order the keys using System.identityHashCode(x) on each HashMap. Then compare similar to this:

[other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193012/4634246)